# sass parent name shortcut need better way

Tags: sass

& is parent's name so I tried

```
.assigItem{
  &--linkedSelected {
    background: red;
  }
  &--unAllocated  {
    background: blue;
  }
  &--linkedSelected&--unAllocated {
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```

but it is not work
I had to do this.

```
.assigItem{
  &--linkedSelected {
    background: red;
  }
  &--unAllocated  {
    background: blue;
  }
  &--linkedSelected.assigItem--unAllocated {
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```

Let me know if there's a better way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use scss [interpolation](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/all-you-ever-need-to-know-about-sass-interpolation--cms-21375).

```
.assigItem{
  &--linkedSelected {
    background: red;
  }
  &--unAllocated  {
    background: blue;
  }
  &--linkedSelected#{&}--unAllocated {
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```

Tested on sassmeister, libsass v3.5.4 — [demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/97ac75d885fdcf5ec7b9c3cd800575b5).